# Use of the article "the" when referring to an organization or entity

Tags: idioms, british-english, articles, north-american-english

Is there a preferred use of "the" in American English when referring to an organization or entity?  For example, [on an episode](https://the1a.org/shows/2018-01-31/are-supplements-nutritional-nonsense) of the ["1A"](https://the1a.org) on [NPR](https://www.npr.org), guests of the show referred to the [U.S. Food & Drug Administration](https://www.fda.gov/default.htm)  as both "The FDA" and "FDA". For example, "The FDA regulates supplements" vs. "FDA regulates supplements."

Is one form "correct" and the other not?

Is this a style choice? In British English, I am often hear statements like "John was in hospital" vs. "John was in the hospital" as one might expect in North American English.

If both forms are correct, is there a name for the two forms?

Comment: I don't think that "in hospital" is relevant, as it's comparable to "in bed". In any case, there are plenty of other questions that discuss that ([here's one](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/19604/191178)).

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate. And the answer is to ask the organization.

Comment: @Drew, I mean in a more general sense. For example "He is in the team" vs. "He is in team."

Comment: *He is in team* is not something you will hear (in AmE, at least). It doesn't sound like something a native English speaker would say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Article usage is idiosyncratic, especially with proper nouns. Popular usage conforms to some extent to the entity's preferred usage— thus, we refer to *the Boy Scouts of America* but *Girl Scouts of the USA*; *the Gold Star Mothers of America* but *Blue Star Mothers of America*; *the Sudan* 50 years ago but just *Sudan* today. No convention is absolute, however. We might think we say *the IRS* because we would say *the Internal Revenue Service*, yet we say *a professor at UCLA* even though the full form would be *a professor at the University of California, Los Angeles*.

In narrower contexts, insiders may refer to some entity in ways not reflective of how the general public would refer to them, forming part of the jargon. This can be a practical matter; within an organization, *she transferred to Sales* might be fully understood to mean *she transferred to the Sales Department*, so the longer form is unnecessary and in fact becomes tedious with repetition. If your office regularly speaks with *the OCC*, *the OTS*, *the FDIC*, and *the CFPB*, you save a syllable as well as make the names more distinct from one another by dropping the article. Or, maybe you just [follow how the boss says it](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408044), or something equally mundane. British clothier French Connection's branding as [FCUK](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/fashion/features/fcuk-the-logo-that-became-a-no-no-7704257.html) is said to have originated with the abbreviation for the head office in London used on fax cover sheets.

For what it's worth, in my anecdotal experience working in and around Washington, D.C., dropping the article implies a certain familiarity, of personification. It is as if you were nicknaming an intimate as opposed to simply identifying an entity. I would liken the difference between *the FTC needs to rule on this* and *FTC needs to rule on this* to that between *My grandmother says so* and *Grandmother says so*. You might use this deliberately to serve as a social signal or [group marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingroups_and_outgroups), even if on a day-to-day basis, you [code switch](https://www.npr.org/sections/codeswitch/2013/04/08/176064688/how-code-switching-explains-the-world) between work and home without even thinking about it. I have not been able to find a scholarly article on the topic, however.

---

The use of *[in hospital](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67036)*, et al has been covered in several past questions, but I think it is a separate phenomenon.